# view-mode-page: How to define the url pattern right?

Tags: views, path-aliases, entities

I'm new here and hope it is the right place for asking my question.

My problem is as follows:

I need to provide 2 view modes of one and the same content type via url. So I installed and configured the module "view mode page", which do the trick for me, but not with the desired and expected url pattern. 
I hope someone has experiences with this module and can help me to find the correct url pattern.

I use Drupal 7.41 and view mode page 1.7.

I will show you what I mean...

It is a blog page which should get 2 different view modes and layouts.

**The original Blog page is available with this url:**

"www.exampledomain.de/de/2016/01/29/example-node-alias"

**The corresponding Pathauto url pattern is:**

"[node:created:custom:Y]/[node:created:custom:m]/[node:created:custom:d]/[node:title]"

I read the [documentation page](https://github.com/robballou/view_mode_page/blob/7.x-1.x/README.md#some-examples-using-url-patterns) for this module "view mode page" and searched for help via google, but I found nothing helpful. In the documentation page are following examples to explain how to use wildcards (%) in url pattern for this module:

**If Pathauto url pattern is:** "project/[node:title]"

**The view mode page url pattern should be:** "project/%/my-view-mode"

**If Pathauto url pattern is:** "category/[node:field-category]/[node:title]"

**The view mode page url pattern should be:** "category/%/%/my-view-mode"

"[...] The wildcard character should be used for variable parts of the alias. This may be the NID, but it could be other things. [...]"

So with that in mind I tried to configure my own url pattern as follows:

"%/%/%/%/my-view-mode"

This throughs a error message similar like this (translated from german): "The URL pattern should not begin with wildcard"

So I tried it like this:
"/%/%/%/%/my-view-mode"

If I use this url "www.exampledomain.de/de/2016/01/29/example-node-alias/my-view-mode", I get a 404 error.

Only if I use following url pattern:
"node/%/my-view-mode"

And open the page as follows:
"www.exampledomain.de/de/node/1234/my-view-mode"

It works and shows the correct view mode page.

**What is wrong with my first and desired url pattern? How can I make this or a similar one work?**

Thank you very much for any advice and sorry for my possibly bad English.

Best regards.